# Android: Slow click response of listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Is anyone encounter the problem of late response when clicks on an item of a listview? I am having this problem and tried all techniques that have been posted about listviews. I am setting a custom adapter that is not populating from database but passing some strings and some Images. And I am using this listview as menu in Side Menu Navigation and on click of list items it opens a new activity in the tabhost. I am just wonder with this behavior even I tried many code optimization.

Comment: This might be happened becoz your side menu navigation not disappear Properly and your ListView data binding might be take long time.

Comment: @SimplePlan In the same listview some Items click response is good but some having this problem where an activity contains textviews with imageviews and it is good where activity just have textviews.

Comment: how you load ImageView images in your ListView ?

Comment: Loading images from resources using lazyadapter's getview

Comment: oohh then there is no issue about loading but i doubts this issue cause from different? post yuor code